# ORA-00001: unique constraint violated, because of the sequence that created new id's in the table

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jboss

I have two tables: OPERATION and TRAVEL. OPERATION's primary key is ID, which is incremented by 1 and has no meaning besides being the id of table. I've created all of TRAVEL's columns in OPERATION and then have inserted all the data from TRAVEL to OPERATION.

Query was basically like this:

```
insert into OPERATION (id, .....20 more columns)
select MYSEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, ......20 more columns
from TRAVEL
```

Now; when I want to insert new data to OPERATION from UI (I use Jboss7, Hibernate, JSF by the way) with form, this error happens. I think somehow id is still set on the first value of MYSEQUENCE so it cannot create the row that UI is trying to insert. Because there is a conflict now.

Am I right with my assumptions? If I am, what should I do about my constraint (id) to avoid this conflict?

**Sorry if things are vague, this is my first post here.*

Comment: Please show the constraint declaration and the table schemas, etc., and the complete error message.

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your `Operation` entity, too. Hibernate should be incrementing the same sequence, but only if you defined your entity correctly.

Comment: how do you set the id   when you insert new data to OPERATION from UI ?? in the insert statment or from trigger or on the other way?

Comment: Check your sequence definition. Does it have a MAXVALUE? Maybe it already hit it.